# Remove line in html/css Tumblr theme

Tags: html, css, themes, tumblr, tumblr-themes

Trying to remove [this line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzrVL.jpg) in this Tumblr theme, but can't find in the code.

Any suggestions?

[link to Theme](https://www.tumblr.com/theme/8952)

Comment: Please consider adding code or linking up to your site where we could inspect it, or add jsfiddle/codepen example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tumblr webpage has a background image that adds those lines.

```
#content {
    background: url(http://static.tumblr.com/cc4ocei/cMdkzipvh/borders.png) repeat-y left;
}
```

To remove the two lines, remove the background image.

```
#content {
    background: white;
}
```

Comment: Amazing. I would have never picked that up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the #content div has a background image, containing 2 of the "borders". So you can overwrite it with `#content { background: none !important; }`, but this would also remove the right border of the column.